# Links in Google searches and Inbox mails get rewritten to lnkr.us

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, gdb

I have switched off every extension except uBlock Origin (edit: now I tried disabling that too) and this still happens: links in Google searches and Inbox mails get rewritten to lnkr.us. I have checked with developer tools and this is not in the HTML source. This happens on click. Then uBlock Origin brings up the "document blocked" tab, I close it and if I click again, it goes straight to where it should. I am quite clueless as to what can cause this. I have seen others complaining and pinning it on this extension or that but as I said: I have disabled all my extensions. I am on Linux and hopefully malware free.

Looks like this:

> https://lnkr.us/get?sourceId=5&uid=50639x1413x&format=go&host=icontent.us&out=http%3A%2F%2Flink.freedompopaccount.com%2Fu.d%3FZ4GuEv3xXUytsV84j81iW%3D3361&ref=https%3A%2F%2Finbox.google.com%2Fu%2F0%2F

A most curious example of this is:

> http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201601.mbox/%3CCA+gyi+0DXFUBw5NYoyKFsvn-zxJ_65KJS_S8UxSHgHzSqsfNUQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

where the mangled URLs got into the mailing list archive.

Another is:

> https://www.reddit.com/r/urbanplanning/comments/471v0k/the_distorted_dna_of_your_community/

The real question is: how can I debug what happens. I can read C, I have used gdb but I am no master of it to say the least.

Edit: nothing unusal on `chrome://plugins` either.

Edit2: sometimes it's icontent.us ; apparently that has been there for a year now, check https://twitter.com/baio1980/status/557236850486960128 the link there.

Edit3: I think this doesn't happen in Incognito mode so it might be an extension still but how can an extension stay alive after ticking it off on the Extensions screen?

Edit4: I have created a new `~/.config/google-chrome` directory , disabled syncing extensions, reinstalled all my extensions and this doesn't happen now. My apps and plugins are the same.

Comment: I assume you have verified that this does not happen in other browsers too?

Comment: Just to provide extra info, I added yesterday `lnkr.us` and `icontent.us` to uBlock Origin's filters, after I stumbled on reports that some people are apparently suffering from link hijacking to these two domains. By having these filters into uBO, this allows to make sure people are informed their links are being hijacked -- without them the quick redirections are otherwise very easy to miss. Did you also look in `chrome://apps`?

Comment: Yeah, my apps screen is just Google's stuff and Slack.

Comment: Maybe helps to check plugins: "chrome://plugins/"

Comment: @R.Hill that's a Windows problem.

Comment: Try also `chrome://inspect/`, from my end I can see stuff in there that does not show either in Extensions or Apps. There is also `chrome://components/`, `chrome://memory-redirect/`.

Comment: Just to be sure... After you disabled an extension, did you force a full page reload of the page you tested (F5)? This needs to be done because an extension's injected script will still be injected even when you turn off the extension, until a full page reload is forced. (even better, <Shift>-F5)

Comment: Re. "I have created a new ~/.config/google-chrome": it would be interesting to see if and what is the difference of the content of the `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions` directory before and after.

Comment: Remove [RSS Live Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-live-links/hcamnijgggppihioleoenjmlnakejdph), that is likely the culprit. Easy to confirm: With RSS Live Links enabled, load front page of Hacker News, and see that a script tag appearing at the end of the DOM, with `src` attribute of `https://icontent.us/585acfe2271e0c5950.js` (on my side). You can spot instances of `lnkr.us` in this script. Disable RSS Live Links and the script for `icontent.us` is not longer appended. Furthermore, the extension reports your browsing history to `eyeglo.top` for each single page you visit.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how this can be seen using dev console: http://i.imgur.com/jpmkFZW.png

Comment: Wow. So the discovery problem was after disabling scripts I didn't force-reload. Pity. RSS Live Links was really useful. Apparently http://ryanboots.com/rss-live-links-rip the extension was sold multiple times and this article suggests an alternative.

Comment: How'd you narrow it down to RSSLL? I'm seeing this same behaviour but I dont have RSSLL.

Comment: @OverlordQ In hindsight: extensions with `unsafe-eval` in the `content-security-policy` property in their manifest file should be further investigated. If you can `grep` your `Default/Extensions` folder for `unsafe-eval` see if there are any such extensions. If any, next step is to investigate further those extensions.

Comment: Only thing with unsafe-eval is uBlock.

Comment: @OverlordQ It has to be in the manifest file. uBlock Origin uses this not in the manifest file, it's to implement inline script blocking. You should lists your extensions so that someone may check -- possibly on a more appropriate forum. There is not really special trick, it requires digging into extensions' code.

Comment: @chx If this is solved, could you write the answer what was the actual solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new ~/.config/google-chrome directory , disabled syncing extensions, reinstalled all my extensions and this doesn't happen now. My apps and plugins are the same.